# Server to Server Authentication in GCP using Service Accounts

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, service-accounts

We have two Django backend applications running on GCP, let’s call it `A` and `B`. Both of these applications have a URL which can be accessed via web and many of the endpoints are secured, i.e; you require to be logged in to access the endpoint. Apart from the user authenticated URLs, I want a secure endpoint (let’s call it `/server-secure`) in application server `B` to be accessible ONLY by application server `A`. Which means I need to authorise and verify requests coming in at `/server-secure` URL to make sure they are coming from server `A`.

I would like to use the server `A`’s **metadata to generate a signed instance token** which I will use to verify the identity of the server. This is not an issue, because I can easily achieve this using Google Auth python library:

```
import google.auth
import google.oauth2.id_token
import google.auth.transport.requests

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
target_audience = "https://pubsub.googleapis.com"

token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(request, target_audience)
```

I have also been able to decode the token on the other end:

```
from google.oauth2 import id_token

request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
print(id_token.verify_token(token, request))
```

My main issue is that I would like the communication to happen only and only if server `A` has a certain service account attached. There is one way to check this; which is to use the `email` key in the **decoded token dictionary** and check if it’s value is equal to some service account, but just out of curiosity, is there a better way to this?

Or, is it possible to create custom role (like "***access-to-server-B***") and authorise the request ONLY if the **service account contains this specific role**???

Comment: The service you are using is important. For example, VPC firewall rules support specifying a service account. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#serviceaccounts

Comment: But I want to limit it to only a few endpoints, not the entire application.

Comment: Google Cloud IAM knows nothing about routes in your app.

Comment: So the solution I have posted is the best way to authenticate between applications running on VMs in GCP using service accounts?